# How to transform this web.config section?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have following config for my mail:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="foo@bar.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:/test"/>
        <network host="localhost" userName="" password=""/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This is my .Release version:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="foo@bar.com" xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(deliveryMethod)">
        <network xdt:Transform="Replace" host="192.168.1.9" userName="" password="" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

How do I remove

```
<specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:/test"/>
```

so it doesn't show in my .Release at all?

Also, I would like to remove other namespaces like `System.Diagnostics` completely. What is the syntax for doing so?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For `specifiedPickupDirectory` element this should work:

`<specifiedPickupDirectory xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />`.

For System.Diagnostics:

`<system.diagnostics xdt:Transform="RemoveAll"></system.diagnostics>`

Answer (score 16):

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="foo@bar.com" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <network xdt:Transform="Replace" host="192.168.1.9" userName="" password="" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This will replace that entire tag with yours.. hope this is what you are looking for..

the good thing about this is that you dnt end up polluting your transform config with unnecessary remove commands like some of the answers stated here..

consider the case where you have more than one child tags..

Comment: I have tried and tested this and use it regularly for my transforms

Comment: I prefer replacing the entire section my self, especially if later you need to modify the elements that you didn't account for.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to remove the config from your release version, can you take it from the base version and just add it to the .Debug version?  That might be simpler.  However if you want to remove it I think you can use `<specifiedPickupDirectory xdt:Transform="Remove"/>` or something similar.

Comment: Not sure why people downvoted this suggestion, I will upvote it. In my case debug is my test server and release productions server. I'm using base version for development.

Comment: Good answer (+1).  However it should be pointed out that when a web app is executed from within visual studio it does NOT do the config transform.  Which means we have to leave a fair amount of stuff in the regular web.config that must be removed.  Transformations only occur on publishing the sites.  This might be a non-issue if you only test by publishing either to the local IIS server or a remote dev server.

Answer (score -4):

@katit , you should maintain two different configs for dev and release.

your webconfig should be dynamic and take the configs as below

```
/qa/yoursettings.config


/release/yoursettings.config
```

one more sample

```
<connectionStrings configSource="config\qa\connectionStrings.config"/>
```

when you go to qa or release , switch your web.config accordingly.

in this way it will be lot cleaner.

Comment: I like the way VS2010 transforms and publishes web.config for me. Therefore question.. I'm doing lot's of other transformations and it is much easier then to have different configs and publish them manually.

Comment: -1: he explicitly asked about web.config transforms, a feature of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I agree with John.  He is asking about config transformations and your code is a throwback to the days before we had that capability.